# ASP.NET Core area link ( /?Area=admin )

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I created an area, but I have a problem. I use redirection with `@url.action` or tag helpers in the form tag.

```
<a asp-action="AddPage" asp-controller="Orders" asp-area="admin">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home",new{Area="admin"})">Admin Sayfasi</a>
```

But it keeps redirecting me to a page like this.

```
https://localhost:44357/?Area=admin
```

When I check what these codes turn into through the browser, I see something like this.

```
<a href="/Orders/AddPage?area=admin">Link</a>
<a href="/?Area=admin">Admin Sayfasi</a>
```

I don't actually have any visible code errors for this to happen, but I can't find the reason why.

My endpoints extension in my `Startup.cs` file is as follows:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
       name:"admin",
        areaName:"admin",
        pattern: "admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Can you help me how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Add Area Route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0) documentation:

> In general, routes with areas should be placed earlier in the route table as they're more specific than routes without an area.

You need to place the Area routes at the beginning of the route table.

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
       name:"admin",
        areaName:"admin",
        pattern: "admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

[image]

Comment: Wow ! I can't believe this worked how hard I worked to figure this out, :) thank you.